# Why did Toolbar replace ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

As of Android L, we have a `Toolbar` instead of the `ActionBar` although its usages seems the same. They even made back compatibility for `Toolbar` via support library.

What was the reason they replaced `ActionBar` with a `Toolbar`?

Comment: "we have a Toolbar instead of the ActionBar" -- no, [you still have `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html). You *also* have `Toolbar`. "What was the reason they replaced ActionBar with a Toolbar?" -- they did not replace `ActionBar` with `Toolbar`.

Comment: When I said replace, I meant that they are advising we use Toolbar as of now.

Comment: "I meant that they are advising we use Toolbar as of now" -- got a link?

Comment: Yes.  Now I am really confused :). I though we would simply use Toolbar instead of ActionBar, but you're saying that we can still use both? If yes,I should probably post a new question asking when to use one and when another.

Comment: "you're saying that we can still use both?" -- sure. Otherwise, hundreds of thousands of Android apps would fail to run on Android 5.0+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toolbar was added because UIs have evolved past the limitations of the ActionBar.  The main difference is that the Toolbar can be decoupled from an Activity's opaque window decor and placed in your custom layout somewhere.  From there, you have the freedom to do some more interesting things with the Toolbar.  One common example is growing or shrinking the height based on scrolling.

From the [Toolbar Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html).

> A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within
>   application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an
>   Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar
>   may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view
>   hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the
>   action bar for an Activity using the setActionBar() method.
>
> Toolbar supports a more focused feature set than ActionBar. From start
>   to end, a toolbar may contain a combination of the following optional
>   elements:
>
> - A navigation button. This may be an Up arrow, navigation menu toggle, close, collapse, done or another glyph of the app's choosing.
>     This button should always be used to access other navigational
>     destinations within the container of the Toolbar and its signified
>     content or otherwise leave the current context signified by the
>     Toolbar. The navigation button is vertically aligned within the
>     Toolbar's minimum height, if set.
> - A branded logo image. This may extend to the height of the bar and can be arbitrarily wide.
> - A title and subtitle. The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content
>     contained there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended
>     information about the current content. If an app uses a logo image it
>     should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.
> - One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the
>     layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity
>     value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the
>     available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have
>     been measured.
> - An action menu. The menu of actions will pin to the end of the Toolbar offering a few frequent, important or typical actions along
>     with an optional overflow menu for additional actions. Action buttons
>     are vertically aligned within the Toolbar's minimum height, if set.
>
> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually
>   distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The
>   use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged
>   on API 21 devices and newer.